# Blank output in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

So my SIM900 GSM Shield is working fine with Netlight LED blinking and Status LED solid light, after I upload the code nothing happens about *mySerial()* in my serial monitor. Can I take your time for you to check this code out? I wonder if the problem lies here.

```cpp
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM900
SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); //SIM900 Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #7 & #8

/*void SIM900power()
{
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  delay(3000);
}*/
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM900
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Handshaking with SIM900
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Signal quality test, value range is 0-31 , 31 is the best
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?"); //Check whether it has registered in the network
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+COPS?"); // Check that you're connected to the network;
  updateSerial();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `SIM900power()`? You defined it but never used it.

Comment: I've just commented it and yet it only outputs "initializing.."

Comment: your code contains a command that forces the arduino to stop and do nothing for 500 ms with every iteration of loop()

Comment: look at the arduino software serial example code and compare it to your code

Comment: This is the site where I copy the code: [link](https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim900-gsm-shield-arduino-tutorial). It didnt explain the part about why it was delay(500) so Im not aware of it how works. @jsotola

Comment: I will reconsider your suggestion. :)

Comment: Are you sure, that you are using the correct baudrate? When the communication does not work, but the module is behaving correctly otherwise, this might be the problem.

Comment: I figured it out! Silly me. I just rewired it. Thanks for all of your opinion. :D

Comment: @TechHermit Then please either answer your own question or delete the question. The comments are not permanent. If they get deleted others will think, that this problem wasn't solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Check RX TX connections
Step 2) Change your baud rate to 115200. Turn off your arduino. Turn off gsm. Start your gsm first and then your arduino.

or 
Step 3) Upload Software Serial code and just send "AT" without quotes using serial monitor. If your connections are correct you should get reply as AT.
Also make sure to set the baud rates to 115200.
Most of the GSM modules have default baud rate at 115200 or have auto baud adjustment enabled but need to be power cycled.